# Show that decomposition group $G_v$ of $v$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{K_v}/K_v)$

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

Let $K$ be a number field,  $v$ a finite place. Let $\bar{v}$ be the unique extension of $v$ from $K_v$ to $\overline{K_v}$.  We fix an embedding $i:\overline{K} \to \overline{K_v}$, then we have a valuation $v^{\bullet}$ on $\overline{K}$ which is the restriction of $\bar{v}$ to $\overline{K}$.

Define the decomposition group $G_v:=\{\sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(\overline{K}/K) | \sigma (v^{\bullet})=v^{\bullet}\}$

Now my question is  how to show the decomposition group $G_v$ of $v$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{K_v}/K_v)$ ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well, can you define an application $Gal(\overline{K_v}/K_v) \rightarrow G_v$? And another one, $G_v \rightarrow Gal(\overline{K_v}/K_v)$ (use that for the $v^{\cdot}$-topology, $\overline{K}$ is dense in $\overline{K_v}$).

Comment: @Mindlack We could apply $Gal(\overline{K_v}/K_v)$ directly by restriction. And for another one, maybe we could extend an element of $Gal(\overline{K}/K)$, but then do we need to show $\overline{K_v}$ is completion of $\overline{K}$ with respect to $v^\bullet$?

Comment: Yes, that’s the idea for both. Though $\overline{K_v}$ is the completion of “nothing” because it’s not complete. You just need to show instead that wrt the $v^{\cdot}$ topology, $\overline{K}$ is dense.